# Is kafka topics still immutable even deployed on kubernetes pod?

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka, confluent-schema-registry

I have deployed a kafka topics and schema registry on a kubernetes pod, I tried to modify/change the manifest file of kafka topics and schema registry, then the behavior of schema registry is in CrashLoopBackOff after I have modified changes and restarted both kafka topics and schema registry, the question is kafka topics still immutable even deployed on a kubernetes pod? can't find any documentation that explain this, and I'm also a beginner when it comes to kafka.

additional infomation on the kubectl logs of the pod is this error message

`The retention policy of the schema topic _schemas is incorrect. Expected cleanup.policy to be 'compact' but it is delete`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without a persistent volume claim, topics aren't kept when the broker pods restart. Perhaps that's why the registry is crashing; the topic no longer exists or is misconfigured?

Otherwise, Kubernetes doesn't affect how Kafka topics actually work. Their configurations can be altered, but the records within are still immutable, yes.

Comment: the kafka topics pod is currently running and upon checking on the pod of schema registry it seems that i got this error message ```The retention policy of the schema topic _schemas is incorrect. Expected cleanup.policy to be 'compact' but it is delete```

Comment: To start over, stop the registry, delete the _schemas topic, then restart the registry. It should create it correctly as a compact topic. Otherwise, create it manually with one partition and ensure `cleanup.policy=compact`

Comment: tried this ```To start over, stop the registry, delete the _schemas topic, then restart the registry. It should create it correctly as a compact topic.``` and this solved the problem, the schema registry pod is currently running now, tried to test the application and it also works!

Comment: just a follow up question, may I know what is the proper way when doing a modification on a manifest of the kafka topics and schema registry, should I not change anything from the kafka topics manifest? due to the nature of it being immutable?

Comment: I assume you are using Strimzi? Then you should be able to modify most of the KafkaTopic resource configuration